# create custom REST API in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, api, rest-api

I want to create my own `custom REST API` in my magento site. I am new in magento api. I have followed following tutorial to learn to put authentication for particular consumer added in magento rest consumer

1. http://inchoo.net/magento/configure-magento-rest-and-oauth-settings/
2. http://inchoo.net/magento/consuming-magento-rest-zend_oauth_consumer/

I have sat all the settings in `REST-Oauth consumers`,`REST-Roles`,`REST-Attributes` and `user permission` as per 1st tutorial

also added controller which should return be login screen as mentioned in tutorial 2

It says magento.loc/restconnect/test link will redirect you some login screen

when i fire my local controller url : 
   localhost/offer/restconnect/test/

it redirects me in following which gives `404 not found` : 
  localhost/offer/admin/oAuth_authorize?oauth_token=47dc6c43fdc972879a761ad1370318e2

Anyone have any idea at which point i am getting wrong or which things i am missing to do.
I have used correct `consumerKey` and `consumerSecret` in `TestController`

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue solved! Got API authentication server login screen successfully. Problem was in my value `authorizeurl` set in $param array in TestController. I have changed it to 'authorizeUrl'=>'localhost/offer/admin/oauth_authorize' from 'authorizeUrl'=>'localhost/offer/admin/oAuth_authorize'. small 'a' letter solved the issue. :)